# element click intercepted error in Selenium / Java - collapsible button

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

I got this error message while trying to click on a specific collapsible button.

> element click intercepted: Element Filters is not
> clickable at point (522, 265). Other element would receive the click:
>
> ...

This button has this:

```
<button class="action-default _active" data-action="grid-filter-expand" data-bind="css: {_active: hasVisible() &amp;&amp; $collapsible.opened()}, disable: !hasVisible(), toggleCollapsible, i18n: 'Filters'">Filters</button>
```

It's XPATH:

```
//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/button
```

I did this:

```
WebDriverWait wait6 = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(10)); 
WebElement elementProd44 = wait6.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"container\"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/button")));
elementProd44.click();
```

What am i doing wrong?

Note: i cannot share the URL because it is hidden.

Comment: Can you at least post that specific page's full HTML source?

Answer (score 0):

Try with following xpath options

```
WebDriverWait wait6 = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(10)); 
WebElement elementProd44 = wait6.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='Filters']")));
elementProd44.click();
```

If you get the same issue, then use the JavascriptExecutor to click

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Filters']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```

Comment: Hey pal, thanks for replying!.
I'm getting this error: "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <button class="action-default" data-action="grid-filter-expand" data-bind="css: {_active: hasVisible() &amp;&amp; $collapsible.opened()}, disable: !hasVisible(), i18n: '...', toggleCollapsible">Filters</button> is not clickable at point (522, 265). Other element would receive the click: <div data-role="spinner" data-component="company_listing.company_listing.company_columns" class="admin__data-grid-loading-mask">...</div>"

Comment: I tried both options, no one really worked :/

Comment: Is it possible to share the url? code should have worked.

Comment: Pal, the problem is in here. (By.xpath("//button[text()='Filters']") 
Is there any other way to define the xpath?

Comment: Could you please list all the different way to invoke that button by it's xpath or a different way?